# Selenium throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium, appium-android

When I run my appium code for mobile automation, I get the following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. 
(WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Appium server version: 1.6.3
Android version: 6.0
Can any one please help me to solve the issue

Comment: It's maybe because you are searching an element with its id, in wrong screen / wrong div. Or else if you are sure, share your code snippet

Comment: Check whetther element is in frame???

Answer (score 0):

This is known WDA issue. Update your Appium to 1.6.6-beta and try again

Comment: May be element is inside of a something like frame or iframe.? The element is slow to load?. Or is in popup ?
You can try to find more higher element and go to this element step by step .